# Is there a way to know how many items are sold until the end of the day after being considered a hit?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Let's imagine that we have this dataset.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


# create list
```

```
data = [['10/1/2019 08:12:09', np.nan, 0, 54], ['10/1/2019 09:12:09', '10/1/2019 08:52:09', 1, 54], ['10/1/2019 10:30:19','10/1/2019 10:10:09', 1, 3], 
        ['10/1/2019 13:07:19', '10/1/2019 12:52:09', 1, 12], ['10/1/2019 13:25:09', np.nan, 0, 3],
       ['10/1/2019 17:52:09', np.nan, 0, 54], ['10/1/2019 18:21:09', np.nan, 0, 12],
       ['10/2/2019 10:52:09', np.nan, 0, 54], ['10/2/2019 12:59:19','10/2/2019 12:57:09', 1, 12],
       ['10/2/2019 13:52:19', '10/2/2019 13:39:09', 1, 54], ['10/2/2019 19:52:09', np.nan, 0, 12],
       ['10/2/2019 20:52:09', np.nan, 0, 54], ['10/2/2019 20:57:09', np.nan, 0, 12]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['first_timestamp', 'second_timestamp', 'hit', 'item']) 

# print the dataframe 
df

      first_timestamp    second_timestamp            hit      item
  0  10/1/2019 08:12:09     NaN                       0         54
  1  10/1/2019 09:12:09  10/1/2019 08:52:09           1         54
  2  10/1/2019 10:30:19  10/1/2019 10:10:09           1          3
  3  10/1/2019 13:07:19  10/1/2019 12:52:09           1         12
  4  10/1/2019 13:25:09     NaN                       0          3
  5  10/1/2019 17:52:09     NaN                       0         54
  6  10/1/2019 18:21:09     NaN                       0         12
  7  10/2/2019 10:52:09     NaN                       0         54
  8  10/2/2019 12:59:19  10/2/2019 12:57:09           1         12
  9  10/2/2019 13:52:19  10/2/2019 13:39:09           1         54
  10  10/2/2019 19:52:09    NaN                       0         12
  11  10/2/2019 20:52:09    NaN                       0         54
  12  10/2/2019 20:57:09    NaN                       0         12
```

When we don't have missing values in both timestamps' columns, it means that the hit column has a value of 0. When both timestamps' columns have a value the hit column has a value of 1. My goal is to know how many items of the ones that I have(3, 12, and 54) were sold until the end of the respective day after it happened (only after, not before) a hit equals to 1.

```
  day       item    items_sold
             3          1
10/1/2019    12         1
             54         1
             3          0
10/2/2019    12         2
             54         1
```

Comment: This question is very hard to read. Does a hit indicate a sold item? And what do you mean with after `it` happened? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, for your data, we can do this:

```
# it's good practice to have time as datetime type
# skip if already is
df.first_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.first_timestamp)
df.second_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.second_timestamp)

# dates
df['date'] = df.first_timestamp.dt.normalize()

# s counts the number of hit so far
(df.assign(s=df.groupby(['date', 'item'])['hit'].cumsum())
  .query('hit != 1 & s>0')   # after the first hit
  .groupby('date')           # groupby date
  ['item'].value_counts()    # counts
)
```

Output:

```
first_timestamp  item
2019-10-01       3       1
                 12      1
                 54      1
2019-10-02       12      2
                 54      1
Name: item, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for solving my problem.